# Adding SSL Certificate to Adobe Air Mobile App

Tags: mobile, ssl, https, air, certificate

Do you need to embed your site SSL Certificate inside your app if your 
using HTTPS to connect to your Server.

My SSL Certificate is configure to accept *.Domain.name from GoDaddy.

Currently I have Ignore SSL enabled in order to test my application.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can import your SSL cert onto the Android device - just look under your Settings -> Security tab.  (But that's only if you need to)  Your device may make you enable a form of access security afterwards (like forcing a PIN or pattern).

If you are only accessing your webserver with that cert installed, then it shouldn't need to be installed on your local hardware.